# C++ Initialization of static function pointer array

Tags: c++, function-pointers, static-members, static-initialization

I want to create a static function pointer array, so I can jump to a certain function regarding a received index. Like an index jumper.

So imagine a class like this:

```
Class A 
{ 
  private:
  static void 1stFunction();
  static void 2ndFunction();

  static void(*functionPointer[20])(void);

};
```

Then I would like that functionPointer to get the value of the 1stFunction and 2ndFunction, and maybe even more.
So, how do I initialize it?
As far as I know, when a static member is declared, you can use it even before an instance is created. So I though, lets initialize that function pointer, so later I can call it like this

```
functionPointer[receivedIndex]();
```

So i tried to initilize it like this, in the same .h file

```
void (*A::functionPointer[])(void) =
{
    A::1stFunction,
    A::2ndFunction,
};
```

But the compiler gives me redifinition, it says it's already created.

So, pretty sure I'm missing something. I don't know though, if it is syntax or simply it is not possible to do it this way.
I know that function pointers to class's member functions are different than normal function pointers... But this is a static function, so I believe it doesn't belong to an instance and therefore it should work with normal function pointers.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b190ad02af50c68a), please post an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `A` is different from `streamHandler`, isn't it?

Comment: This still isn't an mvce. Post code without syntax errors which displays the issue you have encountered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following would be a working example that probably achieves what you need.

You need `C++11` for the initializer list.

It is a good practice to initialize the static member in the `cpp` file, as you don't want to have a definition of the static member everytime the header is included (this can lead to linking issues).

You can call `callf` with the desired `index` and have the corresponding function called, based on the initialization of the function pointer array.

The output of the program would be:

```
I am 2ndFunction
```

**Header file**

```
class A
{
private:
  static void Function1();
  static void Function2();

  static void(*functionPointer[20])();

public:
  static void callf(int index);
};
```

**Implementation**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ex.h"

void(*A::functionPointer[20])() {
  A::Function1,
  A::Function2
};

void A::Function1() {
  std::cout << "I am 1stFunction" << std::endl;
}

void A::Function2() {
  std::cout << "I am 2ndFunction" << std::endl;
}

void A::callf(int index) {
  A::functionPointer[index]();
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  A::callf(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But it gives me unresolved external symbol for A::Function1 and A::Function2

Comment: @WerBn make sure you link all of your object files together.

Comment: @WerBn you need to link the object file where you *define* those functions,

Comment: Ya :P
Good point, I forgot to define the functions.
Thank you very much.

I almost got it.
Real problem was the definition of the array in the .h file.

Thank you!

Comment: Btw, do you know a way of initializing dinamically this array?
Just imagine it's not a static array pointing for non-static member functions.
Can you also list-initialize it? I«m trying, but I can't

Comment: @WerBn, maybe you can make a mvce and post a new question for that, not comfortable to use comments :)

Answer (score 3):

Here you have a more modern C++ approach (C++14 needed)
I would advise you to explore lambda functions if you are not restricted to C++03.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:

  using f_type = std::function<void(void)>;
  f_type f1 = []() { std::cout << "f0" << std::endl;};
  f_type f2 = []() { std::cout << "f1" << std::endl;};
  static void f3() { std::cout << "f3" << std::endl; }

  std::vector<f_type> functions{f1, f2, f3};

};


int main() {

  A a;
  a.functions[0]();
  a.functions[1]();
  //adding custom lambda
  a.functions.emplace_back([](){ std::cout << "custom f" << std::endl;});
  a.functions[2]();

  return 0;
}
```

you can add both functions and lambdas to your container.

Comment: Using `std::function` here is incredibly overkill.

Comment: it is more readable and it will allow him to easily use stl algorithms on his function pointer containers. Unless you're in an environment where nanoseconds matter, I wouldn't go down the function pointer route. I will never understand why people are so reluctant to new modern ways of coding.

Comment: `using f_type = void (*)(void)` can't really be said to hurt readability in my opinion, and std algorithms work perfectly well with function pointers. `std::function` is not a "modern function pointer" (whatever that coud mean), it's a type-erased functionoid container.

Comment: Why std::vector ?
Is is static this way?

I would like to stick to old faction and use function pointer without a template.
But thank you anyway :)

Comment: feel free to change it to std::array.

Comment: @Quentin, if at runtime you want to move a lambda function into a container, it is more modern and readable. Also, having them in a stl container instead of an array, helps syntax if you need to pass them around as references. If the code would be tagged as C code, I would agree, but this is C++

Comment: @dau_sama replacing the C array is definitely a good idea, but replacing a plain static function and its pointer by a `std::function` containing a lambda is completely gratuitous. It is not more legible, it does not need to be that flexible, and it actively hurts performance for no reason.

Comment: @Quentin, until you actually need that flexibility, and you have already too much code that it will be impossible to upgrade. 
One could argue that C++ itself is overkill for such a task, you could do it perfectly in C. And even then one could argue that in assembly it would be better. Difference of opinions I guess.

Comment: @dau_sama the upgrade is one typedef away. And there's no question of choosing a language here, it's about not using the heaviest and all-powerful tool to perform the most basic task just because the tool is shiny.

Comment: let's all use "char* " and raw pointers because strings and smart pointers are so shiny!